# Error saying a variable is not defined?

Tags: python, call

```
#Intro
import time
import random

def restart():
    bowlSize = random.randint(1,100)
    bowlStrawberries = 0

def lel():
    while bowlSize > bowlStrawberries:
        if (addCheck + bowlStrawberries) > bowlSize:
            print('You´re filling the bowl..')
            time.sleep(2)
            print('...and...')
            time.sleep(2)
            print('Your mom slaps you!')
            restart()


def addStrawberries():
    print('The bowl has ' + str(bowlStrawberries) + ' strawberries in it')
    print('How many strawberries do you want to add?')
    addCheck = input()
    lel()

print('STRAWBERRY (:')
time.sleep(2)
print('Okey so you have a bowl kinda')
time.sleep(2)
print('And you have a bag with 100 strawberries')
time.sleep(2)
print('So ur mom forces you to fill the bowl')
time.sleep(2)
print('But she will slap you if a strawberry drops on the floor')
time.sleep(2)
print('So you have to fill it up in as few tries as possible without overfilling it')
time.sleep(2)

restart()

addStrawberries()
```

I´m new to Programming, it´s my fifth day today and I can´t understand why I get errors. You propably had similar questions but I am new and I don´t know what to search. I basically want it to restart when I pick a higher value than the bowls space.

Exact errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/***/Documents/strenter code herew.py", line 44, in <module>
    addStrawberries()
  File "C:/Users/***/Documents/strw.py", line 27, in addStrawberries
    lel()
  File "C:/Users/***/Documents/strw.py", line 14, in lel
    if (addCheck + bowlStrawberries) > bowlSize:
NameError: name 'addCheck' is not defined
```

Comment: Strange, when I run your code I don't get `name 'addCheck' is not defined`. I get `NameError: global name 'bowlStrawberries' is not defined`. Are you sure the code you posted here is exactly the code you're running?

Comment: @Kevin I just copied and pasted so I guess it´s the same. I´m running 3.5.1 if that matters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addCheck` is a local variable in `addStrawberries`, meaning it can't be seen outside of the function. I recommend passing it as an argument to `lel`, i.e. call `lel(addCheck)` and define `lel` as `def lel(addCheck)`. Alternatively you could make `addCheck` a global variable by inserting the statement `global addCheck` in `addStrawberries` before assigning it, but global variables tend to be icky.

Comment: It tells me that addStrawberries is not defined: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/***/Documents/straw.py", line 44, in <module>
    addStrawberries()
  File "C:/Users/***/Documents/straw.py", line 27, in addStrawberries
    lel(addStawberries)
NameError: name 'addStawberries' is not defined

Comment: @Batteriet, sorry, got `addCheck` and `addStrawberries` mixed up. Updated the code.

Comment: It is fixed now, thanks for your support, all that is left is that the the if-statement in lel keeps on being true